# Same timestamp in an request

Tags: java, spring

I have this usecase,

1) Get an request to an spring controller
2) do some mapping
3) do some things
4) do some other mapping
 5) call an backend service

So in the mapping step i set an date, I need the date to be same in all mappings for that request. How do I do that in best way in Java/Spring.

Comment: want to change the format for every request or want same format in step 2 and 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

convert the date to string and it wont change in any mappings later, else you should always have to have format in which way you get in all mappings and timezones..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Create a bean with specific format

```
<bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</bean>

<bean id="step2Class" class="XXX">
    <property name="date">
        <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="#{new Date()}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Similarly for the class used in step 4, inject the date value. Which makes the date format consistent.

reference [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-pass-a-date-into-bean-property-customdateeditor/)

[EDIT]

As the spring context file is loaded once while the application is loaded, the date value holds the server startup time.

inject the date format to step2Class and step4Class -- say

```
dateFormat.parse(new Date());
```

explicitly.

Comment: I have an spring issue now, now I always get the date that server has startup, I have experimented with scope but no luck, hear is my bean definition, I want new Date for every request    <bean id="mappingService" class="xxx.xxx.MappingService">
        <property name="date" value="#{new java.util.Date()}" />
    </bean>

Comment: @poyger edited the answer. This way suits best in the spring batch applications.

Comment: i don't follow. I don't need the dateFormat bean, I just have my MappingService bean and I have one more bean ReservationService bean and I want inject same Date in this 2 beans for every new request.

Comment: i decided to send the date in argument call to this to beans, I think that's an better solution than try to inject the date via spring, but not sure.